# RESTful API: Why not use only one base URL for both collections and items?

Tags: api, rest

I was discussing RESTful APIs with a friend, and he asked why it uses two base URLs for collections and items (`/dogs` and `/dogs/1234`) instead of a single URL with query parameters like everything else (`/dogs` and `/dogs?id=1234`).

After some further discussion, I realized I couldn't come up with an argument that wasn't based around aesthetic reasons (meaning the URL looks better as /dogs/1234 instead of /dogs?id=1234).

You could have one base URL that handles both collections and single items for a resource, and it does seem strange that there is this one special case where you use a non-query parameter (/1234 instead of ?id=1234) to reference a resource.

Which leads me to ask, is there a specific, non-aestetic reason to use two base URLs for a resource instead of one in a RESTful API?

- One thing I considered was that nested resources like /dogs/1/fleas/10 seems awkward, but still doable with a single base URL (/dogs?id=1&flea_id=10)

Comment: The nested resources, as you consider, are arguably also an aesthetical issue.

Answer (score 1):

URI design is only one very small part of a REST API, although you would think it is the only thing about being REST-ful given the amount of time spent talking about it. Authentication, content types, response codes, method types (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS), discover-ability and caching strategies are much more important things to consider.

However, when thinking about whether or not query strings are appropriate, first make a determination of whether or not they can accurately represent a resource's state without changing it. Can the same resource (your dog) be identified at that location using that URI (presumably always)? Will that dog change in some way because you chose a query string with ID instead of representing the ID in the path? No, it won't, which is why a query string in this case is just fine. As a matter of fact either of those will do.

Comment: I guess then I’m curious why this convention developed, regardless of whether or not it is a significant part of REST APIs.

Comment: If I had to take a guess I would say the convention started because of Ruby on Rails. To my knowledge they were one of the most popular early adopters of that URI convention with their MVC implementation. The two went hand-in-hand, and others started to follow their example. Although it wasn't anything "new" the developers certainly gave it a mainstream appeal.

Comment: Path separators (i.e., slashes) can signify hierarchical data, whereas query components cannot. So it's a little easier to signify navigational relationships. For your example, `/dogs/1234/owners` would signify the collection of owners *for* dog 1234. That has a tendency to work better when dealing with data represented as objects underneath. But it's by no means the only way to do it.